Proving Jensen's formula using Poisson's integral formula
I've been trying to follow the proof of Jensen's formula for holomorphic functions, provided in the link, and do not quite understand the use of Poisson's integral formula. Given a holomorphic function $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ with zeros $a_k$ inside the unit disk $D$ and $f(0) \neq 0$, the article defines the holomorphic function $F(z) = f(z)/\prod_k (z-a_k)$ and claims that,

since $\log |F| = Re(\log F)$ is a harmonic function, we can apply Poisson integral formula to it, and obtain
$$\log |F(0)|=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \log |F(e^{i \theta})|\, d \theta \,. $$

This looks to me like the mean value property of harmonic functions, but I do not see how it relates to the Poisson integral formula, which to my knowledge, is given by
$$f(re^{i\theta})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2rcos(\theta-t)+r^2}f(e^{it})dt $$
for any $0\leq r<1$ and any angle $\theta$, provided $f$ is holomorphic. But $\log |F|$ holomorphic in the unit disk (I think)... I am able to prove the Poisson formula, but have $\epsilon$-bounded knowledge of harmonic functions, and would therefore rather avoid invoking them to prove Jensens's formula. I have found this proof which only uses elementary complex analysis, but I would like to understand the relation to Poisson's integral formula.
Edit: @BrunoB pointed out that the Poisson integral formula mentioned here is the one for harmonic functions, not for holomorphic ones. Can I derive it in purely complex analytic terms, or is this really a result of harmonic analysis that I cannot avoid (except using another proof technique as linked above)?

Notice that what you want is really just the Poisson integral formula at $r = 0$, which, if you know it to be true for $r > 0$, you can retrieve via the dominated convergence theorem or the likes.

@BrunoB I've only seen the Poisson formula proven for holomorphic functions $f$, but $\log | F |$ is not holomorphic inside the unit circle (I think)? Moreover, I don't see how the Poisson formula would hold for $r=0$, because Cauchy's integral theorem would imply the RHS to be 0, but $f(0)$ is not necessarily equal to $0$?

What you are citing uses the Poisson integral formula for harmonic functions on $\log(|F|)$ from the get-go, which is pretty much the same formula but for harmonic functions instead of just holomorphic ones. As for the $r = 0$ case, the RHS doesn't become $0$, the fraction in the integrand gives $1$ when $r = 0$, and you get the usual mean value formula for holomorphic functions (and for harmonic functions when considering the harmonic generalisation).

Apologies, that was foolish of me! It does indeed hold for $r=0$, but in this case the Poisson formula is just the Cauchy integral formula... Which I assume is the analogue of the mean value property for harmonic functions? So we are back to: can I prove the formula for the function $\log |F|$ on purely complex analytic terms, rather than going through harmonic analysis / mean value property?
